# XML attributes to multiple dropdown fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, combobox

I have an XML file like this:

```
 <xml>
 <item name="NameA" city="CityA" country="countryA" />
 <item name="NameB" city="CityB" country="countryB" />
 </xml>
```

In html I have three selects:

```
<select class="nameclass"></select>
<select class="cityclass"></select>
<select class="countryclass"></select>
```

The intention:

`nameclass` select displays all names - When a name is selected,

`cityclass` displays ONLY selected name's city attribute.

E.g. user selects nameclass NameA, cityclass

select displays only CityA, countryclass = countryA.

Code:

```
var info;
$.get('items.xml', function(data) {
    info = data;
    var that1 = $('.nameclass');
    var that2 = $('.cityclass');
    $('item', xml).each(function() {
        $('<option>').text($(this).attr('name')).appendTo(that1);
    });
}, 'xml');

$('.nameclass').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var that = $('.cityclass').empty();

    $('item, xml).filter(function() {
        return val == $(this).attr('name');
    }).find('item').each(function() {
        $('<option>').text($(this).attr('city')).appendTo(that);
    });
});
```

How to make the second and third dropdown display city and country attribute from the item selected in the first dropdown? The second part of my code is not working.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is in the intention - how to make the second and third dropdown display city and country attribute from the item selected in the first dropdown? The second part of my code is not working

Comment: What is `xml`? You don't define it your code, also there is a syntax error in your code, `$('item, xml)`. Another note is you are trying to filter the `item` elements, the returned collection contains the `item` elements, so you shouldn't use `find` after that.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/webozine/6M67Z/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work if the name attribute is the same?